# how to use stanford parser with threads

Tags: stanford-nlp

hello I want to use stanford parser wuth threads but I dont know how to do that with thread pool. I want that all threads will do this:

LexicalizedParser.apply(Object in)

but I dont want to create all the time new object of LexicalizedParser because it will load 
lp = new LexicalizedParser("englishPCFG.ser.gz");
and it will take 2 sec for each obj.
what can I do?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Guess it's too late but a thread safe version is there: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Comment: Still not clear on how to run the software with multiple threads.  Do you know what flag is used or how to do this @Yasaman?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).
It allows you to keep one instance of parser per thread. Thus any created instance of parser will never be used from more than one thread.

Usually it shouldn't create more instances than CPUs*cores you have.

*For me it is ~4-5 instances (if I disable Hyper Threading on my quadcore).*

---

P.S. *Not related to StanfordNLP.* Sometimes poor class implementations contain static fields and modify them in non-thread safe way. General safe parallelization approach for such implementations would be:

1. move computation part into separate **process**;
2. launch (CPUs*cores) number of processes with computations.
3. use [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) technic for communicating between main/background processes.